# Npgsql connection to PostgreSql: Array datatype

Tags: arrays, postgresql, npgsql

I am working in Visual Studio 2015 using Visual Basic. I am connecting to a PostgreSql database using Npgsql. There seems to be a problem with the Array Datatype - or hopefully I am doing something wrong. Some of my code:

```
Dim aWriter As Npgsql.NpgsqlBinaryImporter

Dim Keys() As String

N_Domain = UBound(myKey_Name, 1)
N_Record = UBound(myKey_Name, 2)

ReDim Keys(0 To N_Domain - 1)

aWriter = Connect.BeginBinaryImport _
          ("COPY ""GAMS Sets"" FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)")
For Rec = 1 To N_Record
    For Dom = 1 To N_Domain
        Keys(Dom - 1) = myKey_Name(Dom, Rec)
    Next Dom
    aWriter.StartRow()
    aWriter.Write(myCase, NpgsqlDbType.Text)
    aWriter.Write(SyId, NpgsqlDbType.Text)
    aWriter.Write(Keys, NpgsqlDbType.Array Or NpgsqlDbType.Text)
Next Rec

aWriter.Dispose()
aWriter.Close()
```

When I run the code I get an error at aWriter.Dispose():
{"42804: wrong element type"}, ErrorCode: -2147467259.

What is wrong? Isn't Text Arrays supported?

Error details:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException was unhandled
  BaseMessage=wrong element type
  Code=42804
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  File=arrayfuncs.c
  HResult=-2147467259
  InternalPosition=0
  Line=1306
  Message=42804: wrong element type
  MessageText=wrong element type
  Position=0
  Routine=array_recv
  Severity=ERROR
  Source=Npgsql
  SqlState=42804
  [Where]=COPY GAMS Sets, line 1, column Keys
  StackTrace:
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.DoReadMessage(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean isPrependedMessage)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessageWithPrepended(DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode)
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ReadExpecting[T]()
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlBinaryImporter.Close()
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlBinaryImporter.Dispose()
       at ConsoleApplication1.Module1.HVL_Write_Set(String myCase, Int32 SyNr, String SyId, Int32 Dimen, String[] myDomain_Name, String[,] myKey_Name) in \\dtu-storage\hela\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GDX API 5\GDX API 5\Module1.vb:line 305
       at ConsoleApplication1.Module1.Main() in \\dtu-storage\hela\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GDX API 5\GDX API 5\Module1.vb:line 638
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: PostgreSQL is telling you that you're trying to write an invalid element in the array. Your example code doesn't provide enough info - are you sure you're filling up the entire Keys array with strings?

Comment: My error was simply that I was mixing up different variable types: "Character Varying" and "Text".